# ng-click in compiled directive not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

The function tied to the ng-click event is never fired. The ng-click is inside a directive bootstrapped with $compile. Does anybody know why the click event never fires? The function is visible on the scope. A [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1Y5RdDYFNzUStyH8Lr0J?p=preview) is provided. The code is as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.datum = new Date('2015-05-01');
});

var link = function($compile) {
  return function(scope, element, attributes, form) {

    scope.opened = false;

    var tag = '<span class="input-group-btn">' +
      '<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)">' +
      '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>' +
      '</button>' +
      '</span>';

    console.log(scope.opened)

    element
      .removeAttr('szp-date')
      .attr('datepicker-popup', "")
      .attr('is-open', "opened")
      .wrap('<p class="input-group" style="width: 10em"></p>')
      .after(tag);

    $compile(element)(scope);

  };
};

var forminput = function($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "^form",
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.open = function($event) {
        // This never gets fired
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
        console.log(scope.opened);
      };
    },
    link: link($compile)
  };

};

app.directive("szpDate", forminput);
```

**EDIT:**
It is interesting that modifying the input tag as follows:

```
 element
     .removeAttr('szp-date')
     .attr('datepicker-popup',"")
     .attr('is-open', "opened")
     // added this line of code
     .attr('ng-click', 'open($event)')
     .wrap('<p class="input-group" style="width: 10em"></p>')
     .after(tag);
```

produces a clickable input element, but this is not what I want to achieve. I want the button to be clickable.

**Edit 2:**

More interestingly, I seem to have got it working if i modify this line.

```
.after(tag)
```

with

```
.after($compile(tag)(scope));
```

Comment: the first param of `link` function is **$scope**, not compile. So, it would be passing the scope of directive itself instead of `$compile` there.

Comment: @Ashis. As a matter of fact I have wrapped the link function into another function that receives $compile and returns the link function. So I think this is completely valid and the directive does work as you can see in the plunker. Just ng-click does not get invoked.

Comment: I cannot pinpoint it, but I have the feeling you are going a very wrong way: The DOM manipulation for wrapping the input is unnecessary, use tranclusion. Compiling the element again (it is already) feels strange - and it may be the reason why your original controller is ignored. Maybe also try isolated scope for your component (but this is a potential improvement unrelated to this problem).

Comment: Check [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/xRdfIeWNtgG95Sg8X2Hl?p=info) out for a possible solution that can still be improved.

Comment: @Nikos. Thanks for the suggestion. But creating the directive as an element is just what I wanted to avoid. Had this before, but then it is really a pain to set attributes as 'required', max and min length on the input element. It is much easier if I create the directive as an attribute and expose the input element and then wrap it with formating in the directive.

Comment: I still feel it is wrong... anyway in that case why don't you try to wrap the element, *without recompiling it* and setting a standard DOM event listener for click event? (Do not forget to call `$apply` in your listener AND cleanup using `scope.$on('$destroy', ...)`!)

Comment: No wrapping it without recompiling is hard because you want to add the `datepicker` directive.

Comment: Got it working. See my two edits above. Still I don't understand why it's not working with my original code.

Comment: I'm glad you solved it, but it still doesn't feel right with all these compilations. Are you sure you clean up correctly? (I hope I don't sound like those grumpy old men from Muppet show :)

Comment: @Nikos. I also feel uncomfortable for not knowing exactly why this is working the way it is. As for now, I don't think I have to do any cleaning up except for removing the original directive attribute with "element.removeAttr". If I don't remove it, I get an infinite loop on the directive.